# How to fix failed to locate file json in Swift

Tags: swiftui

I have a little problem, i try to decode my json code, helping me with tutorial from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tutorial-building-a-complete-project, but my problem is that my function does not detect my file, my error is "Fatal error: Failed to locate data.json in bundle", if anyone has a solution thank you in advance

```
// File decode Json

import UIKit

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String) -> T {

        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }
        return loaded
    }
}
```

```
// File Model

import SwiftUI

struct CharacterModel: Codable, Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable{

    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var force:Int
    var spirituel:Int
    var endurance:Int
    var defensePhysique:Int
    var defenseMagique:Int
    var vitesse:Int

    var mainImage: String {
        name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-").lowercased()
    }

    var thumbnailImage: String {
        "\(mainImage)-thumb"
    }

    #if DEBUG
    static let exemple = CharacterModel(
        id: 1,
        name: "Hippo",
        force: 100,
        spirituel: 10,
        endurance: 10,
        defensePhysique: 100,
        defenseMagique: 100,
        vitesse: 10
    )
    #endif

}
```

```
// My data.json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hippo",
        "imageName": "Hippo",
        "Endurance": 100,
        "force": 10,
        "Spirituel": 10,
        "DefensePhysique": 100,
        "DefenseMagique": 100,
        "Vitesse": 10
    }
]
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let character = Bundle.main.decode([CharacterModel].self, from: "data.json")

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(character) { characters in
                    Image(characters.name)
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("Menu")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: data.json is located in the same path of the xcode file project (no subfolder)?

Comment: yes everything is fine in the same project, ans in the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolve, Swift don't recognize the file, because some properties were written, with a capital letter in my Json file and not in my model swift so..., i'm stupid guys, thank everyone

Answer (score 10):

The file appears to be missing from your project's bundled resources. Open the `Build Phases` tab in your project file search for `data.json`. If nothing comes up, then navigate to the`Copy Bundle Resources` section and add the file using the `+` button located at the bottom of the section.

[image]

Comment: thanks you jfuellert for you time. I checked, and my file appears well in the Build phases

Comment: Thank you that helped, it was missing from the Copy Bundle Resources of the Tests target